# Using NServiceBus on a client with a non .NET hosted service

Tags: c#, .net, nservicebus

I was wondering if it's possible to have a Windows desktop application written in WPF using NServiceBus and something like rails or django or something not .NET hosting web services, and still get the Pub/Sub to be able to send messages back to the client. I couldn't find anything about having a client with NServiceBus, but not the server.

Comment: you can always build a .net adapter that subscribes to nservicebus messages and reposts them using any available protocol (http, tcp, pipes, whatever). Thus, you can talk to pretty much anything.